# Should I normalize along sample or should I normalize feature?

Tags: machine-learning

I want to use normalize data ranging from 0 to 1. At one temperature I generate 1000 sample. I generate data at different temperatures. I want to know that if I have to use normalize data ranging from 0 to 1 then should normalize each sample(along axis=1) or should I normalize along(axis=0) which correspond to features.
    `[0,....,1] #first sample
    [0,....,1] #second sample`

or

```
`[0, 0.3,0.4,0.6]
[0.34,....,1]`
```

Comment: The whole data.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlAdy.png)Normalizing data means you are pushing all your data to the same scale.You should normalize the 1k samples at a time.

You can see the above image link contains formulae for normalization.Take one class it contains 1k values take min and max value in that 1k values and substitute in that formulae and do it for 1k values.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your point. If I am generating 1000 samples at 10 different points and each point corresponds to one class. Then what will be meaning of normalizing the data from 0 to one in this case?and what is 10k?

Comment: Sorry i am correcting my mistake it is 1k only.You have to normalize your data at each point(i.e  1000 samples at a time). You can see the image link   contains formulae for normalization.Take one class find minimum and max value

Comment: I got 2 different answers:) Now got more confused what to do

Comment: Now  can you check the answer

Comment: So if I generate 1000 samples at value 1.0, 1000 at 2.0, 1000 at 3.0, 1000 at 4.0 it means I have to pick max and min value from first 1000 samples that are generated at 1.0, and similarly for 2.0 and 3.0.

Comment: Yes exactly.So that you will get normalized data of each class.

Comment: One more thing plz if in 2D array rows correspond sample and no of columns correspond feature. Then should I pick maximum and minum value along each row or should I pick it along each column?